# Font Support Windows 7

Tags: html, windows-7, fonts

**I am using arial font. But it does not support chinese, japanese .**
Which font support all language in windows 7? Or how can I add chinese and japanese char to arial font?

I solved Problem Use Batang Font for Chinese Japanese and Others.

Comment: I solved Problem Use Batang Font for Chinese Japanese and Others

Answer (score 1):

There is no font that supports all languages in Windows 7, or in the world.

You could technically add Chinese and Japanese characters to the Arial font using a font editor, but that would mean a lot of work and would constitute a copyright infringement.

From your comment and edit (which should really have been posted as an answer, even though it does not address the question you actually asked) suggest that you wanted to ask “what font can I use for Chinese and Japanese characters in Windows 7?” There are many fonts you can use for such purposes, and the choice partly depends on whether you use traditional or simplified Chinese writing.

You can test the available fonts e.g. using my [List fonts](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/listfonts1.html) tool (on IE) with some test input in the desired language.

See also the Wikipedia page [List of Microsoft Windows fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_fonts).

Comment: now i am using batang and it shows russian japanese chinese turkish

Comment: @user2439722, Batang was primarily [designed for Korean](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=25). It has a largish repertoire of characters for other languages as well, but it might not be optimal for Japanese or Chinese. It might even contain glyph variants of Han characters (“Chinese characters” in the broad sense) matching Korean style for them, as opposite to Chinese and Japanese styles.